# How to resolve ip address to hostname?

Tags: java, networking, ip

I have some IP address and I want to figure out what's a hostname of this.
How can I find it?
Java `InetAddress` couldn't get this information I checked it.
IpInfo database have the same result as the Java `InetAddress`.

Answer (score 1):

If its an IPv4, you need to create a 4 bytes array with each byte the part of the address.

```
try {
    byte[] x = new byte[4];

    x[0] = (byte) 127;
    x[1] = (byte) 0;
    x[2] = (byte) 0;
    x[3] = (byte) 1;

    InetAddress inetHost = InetAddress.getByAddress(x);
    String hostName = inetHost.getHostName();
    System.out.println("The host name was: " + hostName);
    System.out.println("The hosts IP address is: " + inetHost.getHostAddress());

} catch(UnknownHostException ex) {

    System.out.println("Unrecognized host");
}
```

Comment: It's doesn't fit for me because of a lot of ips not resolved in this way.

Comment: What can you tell about these IPs ? Are they in your hosts file ?

Comment: @Oleg Can you resolve them differently, like with `dig` or `host` on the shell? If not, then Java probably cannot either. Also note that not every IP address must have a host name.

Comment: @Robert I get IP addresses, for example, for BBC.com and try to get from this IP addresses their hostname but I couldn't get it back because of ```InetAddress``` not resolving this hostname back.

Comment: @Ali Ben Zarrouk It's IP addresses not from my hosts file this is IPs from other sites.

Comment: @Oleg How did you get these IPs in the first place ? The code I did makes an nslookup. Can you give me an example of such IP. As @Robert suggested, can you resolve these ips with `dig` or `host` ?

Comment: @Ali Ben Zarrouk I couldn't resolve, for example, that's IP address 151.101.0.81.

Comment: It didnt resolve to any host for me neither when I try to browse it.
`Fastly error: unknown domain: 151.101.0.81. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.

Details: cache-hhn1550-HHN`

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk It's IP address 151.101.0.81 for domain bbc.com. If you run command nslookup bbc.com that domain will resolve this IP address.